# CSS Print Mode: How to make an element take full height of subsequent print pages?

Tags: css

[image]

When an element grows large and expand into a second print page as shown in the picture. I want it to take the full height of the second page as well, How I can do it?

I tried

- `height: 100%`
- Use absolute positioning
- Use table display

nothing worked

Comment: Seems tricky to me. Guess you should try to anticipate the page layout at a backend level.  What is the real context?

Comment: Trying to print a report where one element is taking roughly 1/3 of the page width and should always extend to the full height of the page when its content grows to more than one page @theredled